# how to create floating button bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, floating-action-button, buttonbar

I want to create a floating button bar in flutter similar to the `floating bottom bar` as shown in the image shared[image]

the above image is from dependency https://pub.dev/packages/floating_bottom_navigation_bar , this is for the page navigation , but I don't want navigation just want the action to be performed upon pressing the button, and the view should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You do not need to put page navigation logic in it and view will be the same
You can directly check `onTap` to know which button user click

```
bottomNavigationBar: FloatingNavbar(
          onTap: (int val) {
            switch (val) {
              case 0:
                {
                  action = "Home";
                }
                break;
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:floating_bottom_navigation_bar/floating_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _index = 0;
  String action = "Home";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Floating NavBar Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Floating NavBar Example'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        //If you want to show body behind the navbar, it should be true
        extendBody: true,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "index: $_index",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 52,
                ),
              ),
              Text("$action"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: FloatingNavbar(
          onTap: (int val) {
            switch (val) {
              case 0:
                {
                  action = "Home";
                }
                break;

              case 1:
                {
                  action = "Explore"; //statements;
                }
                break;
              case 2:
                {
                  action = "Chats"; //statements;
                }
                break;
              case 3:
                {
                  action = "Settings"; //statements;
                }
                break;
              default:
                {
                  //statements;
                }
                break;
            }

            setState(() => _index = val);
          },
          currentIndex: _index,
          items: [
            FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
            FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.explore, title: 'Explore'),
            FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.chat_bubble_outline, title: 'Chats'),
            FloatingNavbarItem(icon: Icons.settings, title: 'Settings'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I already understand this method, I was looking for the floating button bar without page navigation

Comment: You can directly use it . you do not need put any page navigate in it.

Comment: how we reduce the width of bar. For eg- if we have only two tabs then width will cover the entire screen but i need to be place bar in centre with two tabs. I'm not able to reduce the width of bar. Could you please help me regarding this  ?